# How to achieve gapless audio playback between looping on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, audio, android-mediaplayer

I have tried almost every methods but failed to achieve gapless audio playback between looping a single track.

Steps i have tried n failed :

1. Different audio file formats `.mp3` `.wav` `.ogg` using both
   `setLooping(true)` and `setOnCompletionListener` methods but failed.
2. Creating two mediaplayers and looping one after another using
   `setOnCompletionListener`same failed to loop without gaps.
3. Using `setNextMediaPlayer(nextmp)` it worked, but it merges only two
   different or same audio tracks without any gap and stops playing,
   But i don't know how to loop it for-ever .

Any 1 please help me, Thanks in advance .

Comment: I've spent a lot of time on this, and I don't believe there's any possible way without going to native code and writing your own raw audio decoder in C/C++ at the native layer.

Comment: Can't you just combine the `setNextMediaPlayer` and `onCompletionListener` approaches to alternate between two or more MediaPlayers infinitely?

Comment: I found the solution to this problem on my own. Anyway, Thanks to Rich and Michael to your suggestions..

Comment: And what was the solution??

Comment: Using two media-players and Timer .

Answer (score 3):

Just idea. Make loop between 2 media players. Probably you will need to do extra work when MediaPlayer object compleate playback to prepare for playback again in `onCompleation()`.

Disable loop for both MediaPlayer objects.

```
prevMedia.setNextMediaPlayer(nextmp);
nextmp.setNextMediaPlayer(prevMedia);
```